# REG:command line options in robot framework

Tags: command-line, robotframework

```
--outputdir  D:\\Test\\RIDE_TestResults
```

commandline option is used to get output files in the specified folder.

The same option ratherthan using in commandline how can I use in test case level by using keywords.

Comment: No how; at the point when the execution is at a test case or a keyword, the global configs and settings are already initialized.

Comment: What does "REG" mean at the start of the title?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the path of the output file from within a robot framework test. Once the first suite starts executing, the path will have already been set and can't be changed.